# Equivalent of (VB6) IsMissing in C#?

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

Here's what I get in VB6 Description:

[image]

How to do this in c#?

**P.S.** I also don't know how to use optional parameter in c#.

Comment: Thanks, Im currently searching for it right now but my main problem here is the function IsMissing.

Comment: C# does not have concept of "missing" or "not passed" arguments... Showing particular case where you stuck with conversion may make this question more answerable.

Comment: You don't need this in C# or VB.NET - optional parameters must be specified with a default value, so just check for that.

Comment: Sir @DaveDoknjas Maybe I will discuss this in other thread to be more specific. Thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no *exact* equivalent.

```
public void DoSomething(SomeClass A = null) 
{

}
```

There is no difference in C# between the following:

```
DoSomething(null);
DoSomething();
```

The closest you'll get is a null check on `A`. For value types, you can check the default (Though VB6 `IsMissing` does not support 'simple data types').

That is, the translated version of:

```vb
Sub DoSomething(Optional A As SomeClass)
    If IsMissing(A) Then
        'Missing
    Else
        'Not missing
End Sub
```

Is:

```
public void DoSomething(SomeClass A = null) 
{
    if (A == null)
    {
        //Missing
    } else {
        //Not missing
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank Sir @Rob I now get the idea on how to do this in c#.

Keep helping others specially newbies like me. :)

Comment: @jclima05 No worries mate :)

Comment: Plus one. Here's the [vb6 help on *IsMissing*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445048(v=vs.60).aspx) just for completeness